# AWS Secrets Manager and javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have about 7 hours and dozens of try's to get a AWS Secret.  I have followed the AWS example code as well as other examples found here and on other sites.   My current problem is the code returns a Promise in my variable 'p', not the plaintext secret string.  I'm pulling my hair out here...  If it is returning a promise while still pending a resolve; I don't know why it does not wait.  The calling code is in a sequelize.config file and not wrapped in an exported function--thus the `async function () =>` below.

getSecrets.js

```
const AWS = require ('aws-sdk')

const sm = new AWS.SecretsManager({region: 'us-east-1'});

export default async function getSecret (secretId) {
  const data = await sm.getSecretValue({
      SecretId: secretId
    })
    .promise();

  console.log ("returning SecretString:", data.SecretString)
  return data.SecretString;
```

Calling code:

```
if (RUN_ENV != 'local') {
  const p = async function () {
    await getSecrets (DB_PASSWORD)
      .then (function ( value ) {
        return value;
        })
    .catch ((error) => {
      console.log ("AWS getSecrets error: ", error);
    })
  }
  password = p;
}
```

Comment: `p` is just a function. Where do you actually call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple way to get secret strings from Secrets Manager:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const client = new AWS.SecretsManager({ region: "us-east-1" });

const getMySecret = async (SecretId) => {
  const s = await client.getSecretValue({ SecretId }).promise();
  return s.SecretString;
};

// Async IIFE
(async() => {
  const secret_101 = await getMySecret('secret-101');
  console.log('My secret:', secret_101);
})();
```

Your original problem, as @GalAbra suggested, is that your code has `password = p` when it needs to be `const password = p()`. Specifically, rather than taking a reference to the function, it needs to invoke the function.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod !  I've tried this pattern.  Where I get stuck is getting the secret value (your secret_101) out of the (async() => { function and into a more broadly scoped variable.  Is there a way to make the secret variable available outside the async function?

Comment: Well, you could declare `let secret_101;` so it's undefined in the global (module) scope as an uninitialized variable, and then set `secret_101 = await getMySecret(...)` within an async section of code. But you'd then need some way to know that the secret has become available (which happens asynchronously) or has a defined value. This is all standard async JS, of course. You can't use await outside of async scope.